# Is it possible to pass on user session from a PHP or Rails app to a meteor app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meteor, php

I want to create a web application in which the main application shall be built using a PHP Framework or RoR. However, there are some sections only, that need real time updates (e.g., collaborative editing, real time feeds) etc. Is it possible that if a user is authenticated on the PHP/RoR app, the user session data can be passed on to the meteor app ? Can the 2 applications share the same database? Any insight on how do I go about implementing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do what you've asked you should possibly ask yourself if you can't achieve your goals with one tech stack. Having multiple tech stacks like Meteor and RoR / PHP means anyone that wants to work on your codebase needs to know all of these frameworks. Additionally you might be able to achieve your requirements around collaborative editing and real time feeds using PHP or RoR.

Since you have not posted your requirements it is hard to make concrete recommendations but maybe you should list your requirements use the least complicated tech stack to implement it.

Are you aware that RoR 4 has built in support for streaming: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

You might be able to implement your collabaration requirements using a JS library liek Angular or Ember JS which uses Ajax to keep the users screen in sync with what other users are doing.

Also, this blog post on how Trello is implemented might give you some ideas. They have a great web interface for collaboration: http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

With regards to your questions:

1. Two applications implemented in two different technologies can share the same database. You will need to choose a database that is supported by both technology stacks that you want to use. After that, point both applications at the same database.
2. If you authenticate a user in PHP/RoR app, you can then set a cookie for the user. Assuming your Meteor app is served from the same domain, you can then read in this cookie which might contain some kind of identifier for the authenticated users session. Your Meteor app could then check the db to see if this is a valid session for an authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I am about to start a new project and was confused about selecting the technology stack.I am comfortable with the conventional PHP frameworks and really like the new nodejs based ones (Meteor, Derby etc.) I wanted to get the best of both worlds. But now, that you have explained it to me, I think I shall stick to any one of them.